# Pymodbus RTU Server - Handle requests

Tags: python, modbus

I'm using pymodbus to create a Modbus RTU Server.

I created the server in a very basic way from the examples in the documentation.

```
store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0x0]*10000),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0x0]*10000),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0x0]*10000),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0x0]*10000))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

StartSerialServer(context, port='/dev/ttyUSB0', framer=ModbusRtuFramer)
```

My Client connects correclty. The server prints out the Hex-Values of the request.

What I want to do now is to handle the different requests.
For Example: If a client wants to read Register 4128 from Holding Registers I would like to send a value back as a response.

I cannot find any useful examples in the docs (or maybe I just didn't understand it?)
I already tried to subclass `ModbusSequentialDataBlock` and override the `get/setValue` Methods without success.

This is the code of my Datastore. It is very simple and I expect to see the prints in my `get/setValues` Methods. But I don't see anything.

```
class MyData(ModbusSequentialDataBlock):
    def __init__(self, address, values):
        self.address = address
        self.values = values

    def validate(self, address, count=1):
        print "validate"

    def getValues(self, address, count=1):
        print "getValues"
        print address

    def setValues(self, address, count=1):
        print "setValues"
        print address
```

as di,co, etc I used `MyData(...)` instead of ModbusSequentialDataBlock in `ModbusSlaveContext`.

**EDIT**

It turned out, that it was a bug in pymodbus. When using an asynchronus server you couldn't use an RTU Framer.
I opened a bug and it seems to be fixed:
https://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/issues/70#event-213935076

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing things a bit differently...ModbusTCP instead of ModbusRTU...however I have figured out how to get it to return different values which I think is what you are looking for (getValues/setValues). Here you go...

```
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
import sys
import logging
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def getModbusSlaveContext():
    hr_block = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [9999 for x in range(10000)])
    return ModbusSlaveContext(hr=hr_block)

def incdecvalues(valuelist):
    lengthOfList = len(valuelist)
    for counter in range(lengthOfList):
        if counter % 2:
            valuelist[counter]+=1
        #else:
        #    valuelist[counter]+=-1

def updatevalues(a):
    context = a[0]
    register = 3
    slave_id = 0x01
    address = 0x00
    values = context[slave_id].getValues(register, address, count=10)
    incdecvalues(values)
    context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, values)

slaves = {
    0x01 : getModbusSlaveContext()
    }

context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=slaves, single=False)

time = 2
loop = LoopingCall(f=updatevalues, a=(context,))
loop.start(time, now=True)
StartTcpServer(context, identity=None, address=('localhost', 9091))
```

All the holding registers (starting 3001 and there are 10000 of them) are set to an initial value of 9999. Slave ID is 1 and every other register is incremented by 1 every 2 seconds for the first ten registers.

Hope that helps you.

Unfortunately pymodbus throws an error when I try to setValues to a negative integer. That is what I am stumped on...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244730/pymodbus-setvalues-how-to-resolve-error-integer-out-of-range-for-h-format-co

Comment: Thank you for your tipps. See my edit. It was a bug when using RTU and async Server.